# Is my reason for not gambling justified?

Tags: karma

I don't gamble because I worry that I might win. The problem is that by winning I am exhausting my quota of good karma/luck for non-essential material procession (like iphone or money) without which I could still live a respectable life. Is this line of reasoning valid in Buddhism.

Answer (score 2):

In Buddhism, gambling is not welcome. Buddha's teachings emphasize that gambling can lead to corruption and various problems. Gambling is seen as a high-risk activity that can either make someone wealthy or push them into poverty. Therefore, Buddhism advises against gambling to maintain a balanced and virtuous life, avoiding the potential negative consequences it can bring.

Comment: https://suttacentral.net/dn31/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=main&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin#11.1

Answer (score 0):

> I don't gamble because I worry that I might win.

I don't think gambling is your problem, then. You worry that by having lots of money, you wouldn't be able to control how you spend it. I'm not sure what that has to do with money, but more your relationship to money.

A Buddha say's lots of things about money, even how to enjoy money, to make yourself comfortable. Here are a couple of very wise suttas about money.

[To Dighajanu](https://suttacentral.net/an8.54/en/thanissaro?reference=none&highlight=false)

[Debtlessness](https://suttacentral.net/an4.62/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

One can enjoy sensual pleasures, but not more than is good for you...

> These two extremes should not be cultivated by one who has gone
> forth. Indulgence in sensual pleasures, which is low, crude, ordinary,
> ignoble, and pointless. And indulgence in self-mortification, which is
> painful, ignoble, and pointless. Avoiding these two extremes, the
> Realized One woke up by understanding the middle way, which gives
> vision and knowledge, and leads to peace, direct knowledge, awakening,
> and extinguishment.

> [With Rāsiya](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.12/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer you based on the Dharma Sermons I have heard.

A Buddhist does not avoid something out of worry or fear. Also not perform something out of fear. Fear or Worry falls under Dwesha (Anger) out of the 3 — Raga (Lust), Dwesha (Anger), Moha (Delusion) — because you're uncomfortable with winning from gambling assuming it'll exhaust your Good Karma. Goal of a Buddhist is to uproot those 3 things from arising in his mind/thoughts.

Therefore, I'd say your reason for not gambling isn't exactly matching with why a Buddhist would avoid gambling.

A Buddhist's goal is to attain Nirvana by uprooting Raga, Dwesha, Moha. So he doesn't focus on doing stuff that doesn't support his goal unless it's required to survive. Here Buddhist means someone already in the Road-to-Sotapanna phase to Arihat phase.

If "Winning" spends out your Good Karma, why do you assume it'll only happen while you're gambling?

Everyday you're alive is a day you won. Karma spent!
Every moment you feel happy, comfortable is a Good Moment you won. Karma spent!
Almost every good thing happening to you arise from Good Karma.

So, it'll get spent even if you try to save it for another day. If it gets spent without you having control over it, why worry about it? I guess now you can stop worrying about winning.

If "Winning" spend out your Good Karma, AND you can create more Good Karma, why do you worry about a depletion?

More Money means more ways you can create Good Karma. Donate money, food, shelter, clothes, or whatever you can think of to generate new Good Karma. Since you're asking this question in a Buddhism forum, why not spend that money to donate the same for Buddhist Monks? This alone will create a huge Good Karma.

I'd say learning more about true Buddhism will give you more reasons why you shouldn't worry about having a lot of money. It'll also help you find the control you're looking for when it comes to spending money. Hope this answer helps you!